# Three left joins in a row return unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

So, I have this sql query:

```
select
  o.id,
  o.name,
  d.name,
  w.day,
  o.suspended
from resource o
  left join resource d on d.vehicle_ID = o.ID
  left join week_days_availability_to_resource aw on d.ID=aw.resource_ID
  left join week_days_availability w on aw.calendar_ID=w.ID
where o.IS_DELETED <> true
      and (d.IS_DELETED is null or d.IS_DELETED <> true)
      and o.marketId = 98
      and (w.day = 3 or w.day is null)
      and (o.suspended <> true or o.id in (-1))
```

It returns all the rows I need - excep for just one. There is row in table `resource o` which is joined with `resource d`, then it joins with `week_days_availability_to_resource` (there are some rows in this table with `resource_ID` equal to `d.ID`). The issue is that there is no row in the `week_days_availability` with `day` equal to three, so it returns nothing. But I expected `mysql` to return this row with `NULL` value of `day` field - because I thought this is what `left join` actually does. Seems like I am wrong.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move the `where` condition into the `on` clause.

```
from resource o
  left join resource d on d.vehicle_ID = o.ID
  left join week_days_availability_to_resource aw on d.ID=aw.resource_ID
  left join week_days_availability w on aw.calendar_ID=w.ID and w.day = 3
where o.IS_DELETED <> true
      and (d.IS_DELETED is null or d.IS_DELETED <> true)
      and o.marketId = 98
      and (w.day = 3 or w.day is null)
      and (o.suspended <> true or o.id in (-1))
```

The problem is that `w.day` might be equal to some other value, say 4.  The `left join` condition is satisfied (as originally written), but it does not meet the `where` condition.  By moving the condition into the `on` clause, there is no match and you will get NULL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I moved this condition to the `on` clause, but now I have another issue - `day` field of all rows is equal to `NULL`, even if I check in my query that `day` is, in fact, `3`. Quite strange.

Comment: @aga . . . That makes a lot of sense actually -- the left join is going to return either 3 or NULL.  That seemed to be what you wanted based on the question "The issue is that there is no row in the week_days_availability with day equal to three, so it returns nothing. ".